# How do I invite someone in Minecade?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecade (a Minecraft server) I am trying to invite somebody but it won't work. I did some research and nothing showed up. I am on the super brawl builder lobby. How do I invite another player?

Comment: the chat is not being helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just logged onto the server and typed /party and got the following instructions:

[image: instructions for using party command]

so, just do /party invite player